# Julia Set fractal and location on screen

Tags: image-processing, language-agnostic, fractals

I am learning how to make a `Julia Set` fractal. I am using [this as a reference](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/juliamandelbrot.html#Introduction).

I know the math theory behind it very well. I can compute it manually, too. However, what I do not understand is how it is being done in the program mentioned in the reference.

The author has certain variables that determine the `zoom` and displacement and he performs some calculations on it.

**Can someone please explain what they are ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this line (the one below it works the same way):

```
newRe = (x - w / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * w) + moveX;
```

(Ignore the lack of `1.5` factor, that's just there to make sure it doesn't look "squished.")

It's in a `for` loop that assigns values between `0` and `w` to `x`.<sup>[1]</sup> So the leftmost and rightmost `newRe` values are going to be:

- Leftmost:

  ```
  newRe = (0 - w / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * w) + moveX;
        = -(w / 2) / w / 0.5 / zoom + moveX;
        = -(1 / 2) / 0.5 / zoom + moveX;
        = -1 / zoom + moveX;
  ```
- Rightmost:

  ```
  newRe = (w - w / 2) / (0.5 * zoom * w) + moveX;
        = (w / 2) / w / 0.5 / zoom + moveX;
        = (1 / 2) / 0.5 / zoom + moveX;
        = 1 / zoom + moveX;
  ```

Their difference -- that is, the width of the actual rectangle of the Julia fractal being displayed -- is equal to:

```
  (1 / zoom + moveX) - (-1 / zoom + moveX)
= (1 / zoom) - (-1 / zoom)
= 2 / zoom
```

(This whole calculation also works for `newIm`, `h`, and `moveY`.)

This is why **increasing zoom** causes the rectangle we're examining to **shrink** -- which  is exactly what "zooming in" is.

<sup>[1] It actually only goes to `w-1`, but that one-pixel difference makes this calculation a whole lot more difficult.</sup>

Comment: He is basically mapping the pixels to a cartesian coordinate system, right ?

Comment: Yup. The `x` and `y` values in the `for` loops are pixel coordinates, which are mapped to `newRe` and `newIm` using this method.

Comment: `moveX` and `moveY` just allow us to stroll around in the fractal world, right ??

Comment: Exactly! They're just added to `newRe` and `newIm` after the "resizing" to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I am beginning to understand now. I will ask doubts here in the comment if I need help